# Why isn't my if statement working? (graphics.py related)

Tags: python

I'm creating a mini program & I'm trying to check whether the user inputs what I want them to -- They're **only supposed to type** **one** of the following: **happy, sad, angry,nervous,excited** but for some reason its ignoring that entire if statement and even the table (rectangle) I drew doesn't appear as well?

```
 from graphics import *
 win = GraphWin("Moods", 800, 500)

 #Creating the input Box + A Go Button.
 inputBox=Entry(Point(400,250),12)
 inputBox.draw(win)
 colour=inputBox.getText().lower()

 message=Text(Point(400,50),"Click to go next!")
 message.setFace('courier')
 message.setSize(20)
 message.draw(Win)
 submsg1=Text(Point(400,100),"")
 submsg1.setText("(Allowed moods are: Happy, Sad, Angry, Nervous, 
 Excited)")
 submsg1.setFace('courier')
 submsg1.setSize(15)
 submsg1.setStyle('italic')
 submsg1.draw(win)

 clickPoint = win.getMouse()

 #Checking user inputs the right way.
 if not colour.isalpha():
   error=Text(Point(400,300),"Please type either: happy, sad, angry") 
   error.draw(win)
 elif (colour !="happy" or colour !="sad" or colour !="angry"):  
  error=Text(Point(400,300),"Please type either: happy, sad, angry")
  error.draw(win)
 else:
  #Clearing Second Frame, for next screen.
  inputBox.undraw()
  goButton.undraw()
  error.undraw()
  message.undraw()
  submsg1.undraw()

  #Moving to next frame.
  table=Rectangle(Point(50,400),Point(750,400))
  table.setFill("blue")
  table.draw(win)
```

Comment: `colour !="happy" or colour !="sad"` Well, `colour` can hardly be equal to "happy" __and__ "sad" simultaneously, can it? This'll always be `True`.

Comment: In other words, use `and` rather than `or`...

Comment: Ohh i thought the 'or' function meant like either one?? Is the functions 'and' and 'or' like flipped or something? Sorry im SO bad at this omg

Comment: @Nadia no `or` is definitely for either option

Comment: `or` has the same meaning in python as in English...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what is happening with your code is that this line here;

```
elif (colour !="happy" or colour !="sad" or colour !="angry"):
```

this will execute if one of the conditions is true because of how the `or` works. because one of them will always be true (because the user cannot enter happy and sad at the same time).

so for your example you will want the `and` function as then all of the conditions will have to be true for it to run.

```
elif (colour !="happy" and colour !="sad" and colour !="angry"):
```

now to finish off you need to move this line `colour=inputBox.getText().lower()` to below this line `clickPoint = win.getMouse()` but before the `if` because `getText` is an event which executes when you call it, so at the moment when you call it at beginning it *gets* nothing because the user hasnt entered anything yet.

so it should look like this;

```
clickPoint = win.getMouse()
colour=inputBox.getText().lower()
#Checking user inputs the right way.
if not colour.isalpha():
```

Comment: YESSS i get it now omg thank you!! But i changed this error and it still doesnt work :/ Like if i type in 'sad' i want it to move to the next screen and draw the table but the whole screen just closes?

Comment: this could be that because when a python script ends it automtically closes, if you want to keep it open stick an `input()` at the end

Comment: where exactly? Like after my If statement?

Comment: i usually do it at the very end of my script i.e the last line of the program

Comment: Check out [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you can use a negation for the whole condition and flip all the OR to AND and vica versa.

Comment: Ohkay im so annoyyyyedd it still doesnt work?? So even if the user types in the write thing... the error message pops up??

Comment: Yep it works :) Life saver!!!!! Thanks for taking the time to download it as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
elif (colour !="happy" or colour !="sad" or colour !="angry"):
```

use

```
elif (colour !="happy" and colour !="sad" and colour !="angry"):
```

(`and` instead of `or`) as your original condition is always satisfied.

Comment: For some reason its still not working?? Like i type e.g a number and my error doesnt pop up

Comment: User WhatsThePoint just answered it.